# login page using jsp and postgresql not working

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

I am trying to create a login page using jsp and postgress.The login is not working .The index.jsp page always says Sorry, email or password error.

The index page is the welcome page .It points to loginprocess.jsp.and a bean LoginDao.java is called.

index.jsp

```
<form action="loginprocess.jsp">
Email:<input type="text" name="email"/><br/><br/>
Password:<input type="password" name="pass"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>
```

loginprocess.jsp

```
<%@page import="bean.LoginDao"%>
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="bean.LoginBean"/>

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>

<%
boolean status=LoginDao.validate(obj);
if(status){
out.println("You r successfully logged in");
session.setAttribute("session","TRUE");
}
else
{
out.print("Sorry, email or password error");
%>
<jsp:include page="index.jsp"></jsp:include>
<%
}
%>
```

LoginDao.java

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    public class LoginDao {
    //public static void main(String args[]){
    public static boolean validate( LoginBean bean ){
           Connection c = null;
             Statement stmt = null;
            boolean status=false;
            try{

                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
             c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test","postgres", "pgadmin");
            // c.setAutoCommit(false);
                //PreparedStatement ps=c.prepareStatement("select * from user432 where email=? and pass=?;");
                //ps.setString(1,bean.getEmail());
                //ps.setString(2, bean.getPass());
                stmt = c.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM public.\"USER432\" where email= 'a' and pass='a' ;" );
                //ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM public.company;" );
                status=rs.next();
                 rs.close();
             stmt.close();
             c.close();
            }catch(Exception e){}
                //System.out.println(status);
            return true;



    }
    }
```

LoginBean.java

```
package bean;

public class LoginBean {
private String email,pass;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}


}
```

Comment: Are you able to select the user manually. Means with a sql statement on your DB? `SELECT * FROM public.\"USER432\" where email= 'a' and pass='a' ;`?

Comment: yes SELECT * FROM public."USER432" where email= 'a' and pass='a' ; statement works fine on postgresql

Comment: Do you have any other error? JSP, HTML, Java?

Comment: Without page jsp, using just LoginDao.java class you can retrieve data from database?

Comment: i am not getting any error .but loginprocess.jsp is showing status as false

Comment: even in logindao.java i have tried to return true.yet i am getting status as false in loginprocess.jsp

Comment: the beans are here C:\Tomcat\webapps\login\WEB-INF\classes\bean

Comment: and jsp is in this folder C:\Tomcat\webapps\login

Comment: @Abdelhak can you please tell the steps how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps:

1. Try to verify if the connection to database it's, and you can retrieve data from DB.
2. Cologate the bean with jsp without using the input parameters `( LoginBean bean )`.
3. If previous steps are ok.
4. Try to add parameters (email,pass) in your method `validate` not object LoginBean.
5. In your jsp pass parameters like below:

   ```
   < jsp:useBean id="obj" class="LoginBean" scope="session" />
   <body>
      < jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="email" />  
      < jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="pass" /> 
   </body>
   ```